# Google app engine: fails on deployment but works perfectly locally -- nonresponsive html form submit button

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a small yest App running on GAE under the default free quota.  It runs fine locally.  When deployed on GAE (appspot), some parts of it do not work.  Appspot dashboard does not show any error in the logs.  Added code to trap quota limits is not triggered.  Why is there a variation between the App running locally, versus failing when uploaded?  There are no server error screens when deployed, only non-responsive buttons.  (One non-responsive html form submit button, which works fine locally.) I am using Eclipse to run the App locally and also to deploy the same identical code.

Any insights offered would be helpful.  I don't have infinite loops, only a java while () {} statement which locally is tracked to run only 4 while loop iterations within 4 milliseconds.

Comment: There are lots of things that could potentially be different between your development environment and production. There isn't enough information here to point to any one in particular. Since your problem in an unresponsive form button, I suggest you start with Firebug: is there a javascript error before the server-side request fires? If the request does fire, does it time out or finish? Is the response an error or success? Include any details of what happens, especially any errors.

Comment: Drew Sears:
Thanks for the suggestion on running Firebug.  This is for client-side Javascript.  Google App Engine is in java (or python) code, not javascript.  GAE offers the log.info() function to show interim values at any step of the way.  My code is practically with log.info() all over, and it works perfectly.  There are no math or code errors when run locally: all the variables have correct values.  Why the code fails on deployment at form submit without errors is a mystery.  
-- Joe

Comment: @Joe Smallman - Welcome to Stack Overflow! _Please_ edit your question to provide additional information, or leave comments _as comments_ under answers that might need clarification or additional discussion. The 'Answer' field is just for that, answers - not additional information or discussion. I've merged yours into comments as best I could, but some were replies along with additional code.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility:

Check your urls are not having a double slash ('//') e.g. /user//listall 
This works on dev server but not when you deploy it on app engine.